# Connecting to MySQL from remote host using wildcards not working

Tags: mysql

Hi so I am trying to set up my mysql server to accept remote connections from all hostnames by using a % sign in the place of hostname. This however still will not let me connect. My MySQL user table is as follows:

mysql> select host,user from user;

```
+----------------+------------------+
| host           | user             |
+----------------+------------------+
| %              | guest            |
| 127.0.0.1      | root             |
| 197.87.180.*** | guest            |
| ::1            | root             |
| localhost      |                  |
| localhost      | debian-sys-maint |
| localhost      | root             |
| raspberrypi    |                  |
| raspberrypi    | root             |
+----------------+------------------+
```

I am able to connect to the server using the username guest from my remote computer with IP address 197.87.180.* but any other IP it gives me the error **Access denied for user 'guest'@'197.87.**.**' (using password: YES)**

Anyone know the reason for this or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Verify the privileges for guest@'%' with the following:
show grants for 'guest'@'%';

Also, user guest can have a different password for  host 197.87.180.*** and another password for host %.
You can verify if the password is the same for both instances of guest user by executing the following query: select host,user,password from mysql.user;

If they don't have the same password, you can change it by executing the following: set password for guest@'%' = password('newPwd');

Cheers,
JF